# Send SimpleXmlElement via Curl using POST request

Tags: php, post, curl, simplexml

How could I send `SimpleXmlElement` object via `Curl` using `POST` request type and receive `SimpleXmlElement` object back.

I made two files on my local server and created object.

URLs:

- `http://someaddress/fileOne.php`
- `http://someaddress/fileTwo.php`

Object in from first file:

```
$Xml = new SimpleXMLElement( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SomeXml></SomeXml>' );
$Translation = $Xml->addChild( 'Translation' );
$Translation->addChild( 'Phrase', 'test' );
```

and now I would like to send this `$Xml` object via curl and parse it in other file and send back

```
$Xml = new SimpleXMLElement( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SomeXml></SomeXml>' );
$Translation = $Xml->addChild( 'Translation' );
$Translation->addChild( 'Phrase', "Got your phrase: $phrase" );
```

I would appreciate very much if you could provide code examples.
Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: Okay, we got what you want. Now we want to know, what have you tried? :)

Comment: I have my own written curl class and sadly it is private. Tryed to use it to send this object, but as I understand from an answer, that sending object isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't send the SimpleXMLElement object, you would send the XML data.

From your send side, you would:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SomeXml></SomeXml>';

// assuming you have a previously initialized $curl_handle
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
```

Then from your receive side you would just get the request and parse it using SimpleXml.

Comment: So in other words sending object is not possible. Only a string and then converting in to object on other side? And how long could that string be? Could I just serialize object and send it or it would be larger?

Comment: You could serialize the object, but php's serialization support has its limitations. XML is designed for doing what you're trying to do; transfer data. Sending serialized SimpleXML objects just doesn't make much technical sense for many reasons.

Comment: If you're working with php5, I would recommend you have a look at the altumo library's curl abstraction class (https://github.com/homer6/altumo/blob/master/source/php/Http/OutgoingHttpRequest.php) It makes it much easier to work with curl. It also provides an XmlElement class to ease Xml manipulation (https://github.com/homer6/altumo/blob/master/source/php/Xml/XmlElement.php)

Comment: Thank you. Did it. For convenience I created `SimpleXmlElement`, field it with data and then serialized the result `->asXml()`. Then sent it via curl and converted to `SimpleXmlElement` again. Parsed, generated `XML` and send it back. Then displayed result as XML. NB!! Didn't know that `SimpleXmlElement` object serialization is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The only data type that can be passed through cURL is string. You could parse the elements using a function like the below (ref: http://www.nicolaskuttler.com/post/php-innerhtml/)

```
function innerHTML( $contentdiv ) {
            $r = '';
            $elements = $contentdiv->childNodes;
            foreach( $elements as $element ) { 
                    if ( $element->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE ) {
                            $text = $element->nodeValue;
                            // IIRC the next line was for working around a
                            // WordPress bug
                            //$text = str_replace( '<', '&lt;', $text );
                            $r .= $text;
                    }    
                    // FIXME we should return comments as well
                    elseif ( $element->nodeType == XML_COMMENT_NODE ) {
                            $r .= '';
                    }    
                    else {
                            $r .= '<';
                            $r .= $element->nodeName;
                            if ( $element->hasAttributes() ) { 
                                    $attributes = $element->attributes;
                                    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute )
                                            $r .= " {$attribute->nodeName}='{$attribute->nodeValue}'" ;
                            }    
                            $r .= '>';
                            $r .= $this->innerHTML( $element );
                            $r .= "</{$element->nodeName}>";
                    }    
            }    
            return $r;
    }
```

then urlencode( innerHTML ( $XML ) ) and pass through curl.

A word of warning - if you are working with a large DOM Element, the above function can cause server strain.